# POST from android to WCF Service (OData)

Tags: java, android, json, post, odata

**Edit:**

After doing some more experimentation, I discovered that the request will only work if all of the values are quoted in the JSON string. That is to say that this won't work

```
{"Text":"test","RatingValue":0.0,"LocationID":5}
```

and this will

```
{"Text":"test","RatingValue":"0.0","LocationID":"5"}
```

What I don't understand is why. The first string seems to be a valid JSON string. Is this a quirk with WCF?

**Original Post**

I am trying to post a new item to a collection from android. I keep getting a response code of 400: Bad Request. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and I was hoping someone might be able to help me. Here is the java code.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) uri.toURL().openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.connect();

DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
out.write(data.getBytes());
out.flush();

int code = conn.getResponseCode();
String message = conn.getResponseMessage();

conn.disconnect();
```

The data is a JSON string that looks like the following:

```
{"Text":"test","RatingValue":3.0,"ReviewID":0,"LocationID":5}
```

In this case the ReviewID is the primary key.

The URL for the request points to the collection of Ratings. If i paste the same location into my browser, it successfully queries the collection. It looks something like this:

```
http://localhost/DataService.svc/Ratings
```

Comment: Bort,how you are posting this json can u post some code where you are preparing this json object `data'?

Comment: Was there a message returned in the body of the error response? If so please edit your post to include it. On a side note, most REST services do not accept a primary key as part of a create request. The service may be choking on that.

Comment: Try these to enable more detailed error messages and please post what you get here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost hp = new HttpPost("http://localhost/DataService.svc/Ratings");
 HttpResponse hr;
 JSONObject jo1 = new JSONObject();
 joobject.put("Text", "test");
 joobject.put("RatingValue", "3.0");
 joobject.put("ReviewID", ".0");
 joobject.put("LocationID", ".5");
 StringEntity se = new StringEntity(joobject.toString(),HTTP.UTF_8);
 se.setContentType("application/json");
 hp.setEntity(se);
 hr = hc.execute(hp);
```

maybe helpful

Comment: I'm still getting a 400: Bad Request response with this method.

Comment: see my edit i'have updated my answer with `HttpPost` or make sure your WCF service iis running or if u r checking on emulator then maybe any other issue.